# how to allow spaces in input java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java so this is a very basic question. I get and error when entering a name with spaces.  What do I need to change please?  steering me to info is great too.

how do I allow input with spaces.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class yes {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Name = in.next();
        ....
      }
  }
```

Comment: how about using `in.nextLine()`?

Comment: Where the datatype for name is defined?

Comment: @codenut Dude, it's yoda. `in.nextLine()` you should be using, but first `in.hasNextLine()` you should call.

Comment: **Class** name should be Capital first for Java Convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `in.nextLine();`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Yes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       String name = in.nextLine();
       ....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need to change :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Yes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    name = in.nextLine();
    ....
  } 
}
```

Here's why : The `next()` method reads the input on *current line* till a space is detected. It advances to next line only when you press *Enter/Return*.

On the other hand, `nextLine()` method advances to the next line and returns the input on the current line.

You can read more about Scanner class [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Also, it is good to follow Java naming conventions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Scanner.nextLine();` method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class yes {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = in.nextLine();
        ....
      }
  }
```

---

Hope this helps!